# Unable to understand how Playframework works

Tags: java, scala, playframework-2.0

I installed playframework and have a question.I  looked at the helloworld tutorial  but it seems to use groovy.

```
@(message: String)

@main("Welcome to Play 2.1") {

    @play20.welcome(message, style = "Java")

}
```

The first line is the function definition. What does play20 stand for. I am really new to Scala and I cant make head or tail out of it.

```
@(title: String)(content: Html)

    <!DOCTYPE html>

    <html>
        <head>
            <title>@title</title>
            <link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" href="@routes.Assets.at("stylesheets/main.css")">
            <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="@routes.Assets.at("images/favicon.png")">
            <script src="@routes.Assets.at("javascripts/jquery-1.9.0.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
        </head>
        <body>
            @content
        </body>
    </html>
```

This is just standard HTML which accepts html content and a title string. But how is this file getting called from the index.scala.html?

Comment: Play Framework 1.* used Groovy, 2.* uses Scala.

Answer (score 0):

The `@play20.welcome()` part calls a Scala method, not that different from Java.

As for the HTML templates, they're compiled into Scala classes as well, a bit like JSP is compiled into servlets.

Comment: Where is play20 defined?

Comment: Does it matter? it's not like you'll use it in any of your programs. But it's included in the framework and IIRC contains the welcome screen as well as the documentation and some other things.

Comment: Okay. I was just curious since dont we have to import it and tell it the location of where it is. Or does it look for the same function name defined everywhere?

Comment: You could go through the framework's source to see how it's handled, if you think it's worth the time.

Comment: It is there : https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/2.1.3/framework/src/play/src/main/scala/views/play20/welcome.scala.html

Answer (score 0):

The example you are refering to sounds like it's about Play 1, while the framework you are trying out is play 2, which is a rather different thing. Play 2 has it's own template engine.

The @ is the symbol that signals you're going to start a Scala expression. Like < ?php ? > or <% %> for intance in other langauges. The only difference is that you don't have a trailing symbol, because the template engine stops parsing at the end of the expression and  automagicly returns to evaluating the template as html.

play20 is an object that is in scope for the template engine, like things in java.lang are in in scope in a regular java file. E.g. String.

In this case play20 is like a class with a static method in Java.

In [this](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.1.0/ScalaTodoList) tutorial you have good simple introduction to how to use the Play 2 framework